# Product of solutions to Schrödinger equation is itself solution. What is the significance?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, density-operator, observables, quantum-states

Suppose $H$ is a (possibly time dependent) Hamiltonian for some quantum system, and suppose $\rho(t)$ and $\sigma(t)$ are quantum states (in the form of density matrices) which satisfy the time dependent Schrödinger equation (TDSE).

$$i \partial_t \rho = [H,\rho], \quad i \partial_t \sigma = [H,\sigma]$$

Recently, I was surprised to discover that the *product* of the two, $\rho\sigma$ is also a solution. Of course, $\rho\sigma$ might not be a valid quantum state, but this feature still seems noteworthy. Similarly, in the Heisenberg picture, a product of individually solutions $\hat{O}(t)$ and $\hat{P}(t)$ also satisfy the TDSE (though $\hat{P}\hat{O}$ is not necessarily an observable). In both cases, the reason can be traced back to the fact that both $\partial_t$ and $[H, \cdot]$ are *derivations* (i.e. they satisfy the product rule).

While the linearity of the TDSE is considered a crucial property (and rightly so), it seems to me that this multiplicative property is rarely discussed. Perhaps this is for some of the points mentioned above: quantum states are not closed under multiplication.

My question is, what physical interpretations and insights, if any, can be drawn from this property of the TDSE? Does this property find use anywhere in physics?

Comment: I guess this is more or less the same observation that if $\rho(t) = U(t)\rho U^\dagger(t)$ and similarly for $\sigma(t)$, then $\rho(t)\sigma(t) = U(t)\rho U^\dagger(t)U(t)\sigma U^\dagger(t) = U(t)\rho\sigma U^\dagger(t)$, that is it also has the form of unitary evolution. Once you put it like that, this observation (for the Heisenberg equation) is used all the time in field theory.

Comment: 'I was surprised to discover' Where did you discover this?

Comment: "...it seems to me that this multiplicative property is rarely discussed. Perhaps this is for some of the points mentioned above: quantum states [density matrices] are not closed under multiplication." [Bingo.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/bingo_2)

Comment: @BySymmetry Good point, this makes everything much clearer. I suppose this comment coupled with Chiral Anomaly's makes for a complete answer to my question.

Comment: @my2cts Mostly from playing around, but also from thinking about dynamical invariants, which are discussed at the beginning of [this article](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8113/42/3/035307)

Comment: suggest you modify title to “time-dependent Schrodinger equation”…

Answer (score 1):

If the systems are independent (non-interacting), then by simple separation of variables a product of solutions $\psi(x_1)\psi(x_2)$ is also a solution since the total Hamiltonian will split into $H=H_1+H_2$.

Of course it is not true in general that $\psi(x_1)\phi(x_1)$ is a solution if $\psi(x_1)$ and $\phi(x_1)$ are separately solutions.  (Just try it with the product of two $\psi_n(x_1)$ for the harmonic oscillator.) I guess in the language of your question $\psi(x_1)\phi(x_1)$ is not what you call a valid quantum state.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Thank you for the answer, however, this isn't quite what I'm looking for. In my question I don't take $\rho$ and $\sigma$ to exist on independent subsystems. The Hamiltonian is arbitrary and the states are on the entire space.

I agree with your second point that $\psi(x)\phi(x)$ is not a solution, but this is not the same thing.

Comment: @Jacob Fair enough but then what is the meaning of the product?   We agree that $\vert \phi\rangle\vert \psi\rangle$ is not a solution but what is the meaning of this (pure) state, from which I could construct $\vert \psi\rangle\vert \phi\rangle \langle \phi\vert\langle \psi\vert =(?) \rho\sigma$ with $\rho=\vert\psi\rangle\langle \psi\vert$ etc?

Comment: I agree it is meaningless in ket form, but the wavefunction form $\psi(x)\phi(x)$ has meaning in describing the coefficients in the position basis (roughly speaking) of some given state. In any case, this is not the same as taking some product of the density matrices, which is well defined.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow.  Do you mean you just multiply $\sigma$ and $\rho$ as matrices?  There is no guarantee that the product is hermitian (unless the matrices commute) and even then the product will not necessarily be a density matrix.  We are back to the observation of @ChiralAnomaly     that density matrices do not close under multiplication.